# Is there a card action to generate another card in Microsoft Bot framework?

Tags: c#, botframework

Is there any action type that I can use?

I am generating a list of cards which show some products. When the user clicks on them, I want to generate another card with a more detailed description. Is there any card action that I can use to call a method?

Comment: Have you tried Action.ShowCard ? http://adaptivecards.io/visualizer/?card=/explorer/cards/Action.ShowCard.json

Comment: Do you want to do this using adaptive cards or simple rich cards?

Comment: simple rich card

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to use rich cards and not adaptive cards, you need to generate the second card manually.

Basically, the flow will be:

1. **Card 1 with a button**. Once you click the button, you will receive a new message to your controller, with the `Text` being the `Value` of the button (`CardAction`)
2. Based on the message you received, you generate the second card and send it to the user.

[Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/cards-RichCards) you can find an example on how to use rich cards.

Comment: That's what I finally implemented, I thought there might be a better way to do that, a more easier way..

Comment: No, you could take a look to adaptive cards though. It has support for generating a card within a card